# Add attribute to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the attribute of a tag in some HTML code given as an object?

Currently, if I do:

```
console.log(gallery.currItem);
```

I get:

[image]

So I then did:

```
console.log(gallery.currItem.html);
```

And I get the HTML in console (not as an object, I believe it's just as texy):

```
<video width="500" height="250" controls><source src="" type=""></video>
```

But I'm not sure how I would edit the `video` tag by adding the attribute `muted="muted"`.

I tried:

```
console.log($(gallery.currItem.html).find('video'));
```

But this returned an object again. :/

Comment: how is gallery.currItem initialized/set?

Comment: Even though it looks like text in the console, it's the actual element.

Comment: @Sebastian: No it's not. Look at the screenshot.

Comment: All I see is a html element with a "+" for expansion to view the attributes.

Comment: You might be able to do `gallery.currItem.html = $(gallery.currItem.htm).attr('muted', 'muted').html();`, but that really depends on how the whole `gallery` stuff works.

Comment: @FelixKling Here's the library: http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html I initialize it as it's initialized in "Step 3".

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using PhotoSwipe. `gallery.currItem.html` is not a string but an actual html element.
You can just directly edit the attributes of it:

```
gallery.currItem.html.setAttribute("muted", "muted");
```

To make sure it's an actual element, if in question, do this:

```
if(gallery.currItem.html.tagname) {
    gallery.currItem.html.setAttribute("muted", "muted");
} else {
    // append it to the dom or wrap it into jquery and then set the attributes
    gallery.currItem.html = $(gallery.currItem.html).attr("muted", "muted")[0];
}
```

Comment: TypeError: gallery.currItem.html.setAttribute is not a function

Comment: Okay then you do have to wrap it in jquery. Which would be the same as the other answers already suggested. You could overwrite the html property with the jquery object though.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 $(gallery.currItem.html).attr("muted", "muted");
```

Comment: That might produce a new element from the HTML and change it with what's needed, but it doesn't assign back to the gallery.

Comment: my mistake.. try this

gallery.currItem.html = $(gallery.currItem.html).attr("muted", "muted")[0]

Comment: @user5140488: i edited..sorry again try it for last time.
gallery.currItem.html = $(gallery.currItem.html).attr("muted", "muted")[0]

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
$(gallery.currItem.container.lastChild).attr('muted', 'muted');
```